# Issue with text file importing and manipulation

Tags: python-3.x

I have a txt file with this in it:

GWashington 83

JAdams 86

What I need to do is read the file, add 5 to the numbers and save it to a new file.

```
newFile = open('scores2.txt', 'w')
stdLines = [line.strip() for line in open('class_scores.txt')]
scrSep = [line.split(',') for line in stdLines]
print(stdLines, scrSep)
def convert_numbers(s):
    if not s:
        return s
    try:
        f = float(s)
        i = int(f)
        return i if f == i else f
    except ValueError:
        return s

    g = list(map(convert_numbers, scrSep))
    print(s)
    print(scrSep)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

what should happen with this is it should open the file, seperate the lines and seperate the components so then I can turn the numbers into ints and manipulate them. But strip and split are making it harder for the items to be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I fixed it, just had to call from deeper in the list.
So instead of `list[x]` I had to do `list[x][y]`
That uhh... slipped my mind.